# Rails AWS S3 with Paperclip "failed to load resource: the server responded with 403 forbidden"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Let me start by saying, I have AWS S3 and Paperclip image upload working fine. Reference log file below.

I have spent too many hours now trying to track down the issue with Get Method returning 403 forbidden, with what seems to be due to Get appending an extension at the end of the file name.

I have confirmed that I am able to connect with the images stored in my bucket by hard-coding the html source directly in the View, e.g., http://mybucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/..../filename . Image is displayed fine.

Here is the code set-up:

I am using paperclip.rb

```
# config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = '/:class/:attachment/:id_partition/:style/:filename'
```

I am using aws.yml (leveraging aws-sdk)

```
#config/aws.yml
development:
  access_key_id: xxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

production:
  access_key_id: xxxxxx
  secret_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

In my environments:

```
.....

#config/environments/development.rb

# Path to ImageMagick
Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/ImageMagick"

config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
  :bucket => 'mybucket_name'
  }
}

....
```

I am doing nothing special in my Profile model. Here is what I'm using for paperclip:

```
....
#paperclip image attachment
has_attached_file :logo_image, :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :small => "175x175>",  
:thumb => "100x100>" }


# Validate content type
validates_attachment_content_type :logo_image, :content_type => /\Aimage/

# Validate filename
validates_attachment_file_name :logo_image, :matches => [/png\Z/, /jpe?g\Z/, /JPG?\Z/]

validates_attachment_size :logo_image, :less_than => 4.megabytes

....
```

Profile Controller

```
#profiles_controller.rb

....
 def create
@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)

if @profile.save

  flash[:notice] = "Profile has been created."

  redirect_to @profile
else
  flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been created."

  render "new"
end
end

def edit

end

def update
if @profile.update(profile_params)
  redirect_to @profile
  flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated."     
else
  flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been updated."
  render "edit"
end
end


def destroy
@profile.destroy

flash[:notice] = "Profile has been destroyed."

redirect_to profiles_path
end

private

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:id, :firstname, :lastname, :instagram, :company, :website,  
  :street_address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :phone, :logo_image, :address, :latitude,   
  :longitude, 
  :user_id, :user_email_id)
end

def set_profile
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  flash[:alert] = "The profile you were looking for could not be found."
  redirect_to profiles_path
end
```

User Model (I am builing the profile_id via the User Model)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

after_create :build_profile

has_many :tags


def build_profile
  Profile.create(user: self) 
end

end
```

Form View (Call-out: I am not using multipart => "true")

```
....

  <%= form_for @profile, :html => {"data-ajax" => false} do |f| %>
                                           <p>&nbsp;</p>

                                           [form code here ]

                                           <div class="row">
                                              <div class="col-md-4">
                                                  <%= f.file_field :logo_image %>

                                              </div>
                                            </div>

                                          <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                          <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                              <%= f.submit 'Save', :class => 
'btn btn-primary' %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to "Cancel", :back, :class => 'btn btn-info' %>
```

View to display image:

```
....
<div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li ><%= link_to "Offers", profile_path(@profile = current_user.profile), :data => {:icon=>"star"} 
         %></li>
        <li><a href="/tags" data-icon="tag">Tags</a></li>
        <li><%= link_to(edit_profile_path(@profile = current_user.profile)) do %>
        <%= image_tag current_user.profile.logo_image.url, :class => "img-circle" %><br>
        <%= "Account" %>
        <% end %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is the log file on image update. As you can see AWS & Paperclip seem to be doing what they should be doing for deleting old image and saving new image. All seems to be working fine:

```
#log file

....
Started PATCH "/profiles/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-09 17:59:11 -0800
Processing by ProfilesController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",  
"authenticity_token"=>"XJiJcWbhLmeu0eJD1nvVPIDhQGRE4KhdJUlPnpY8HOo=",    "profile"=>   
{"firstname"=>"Jen", "lastname"=>"", "company"=>"", "website"=>"", "city"=>"", "state"=>"", 
"phone"=>"", "address"=>", , , ", "latitude"=>"", "longitude"=>"", "logo_image"=>#
<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x511bfc0 @tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/RackMultipart20141109-12208-1wc9lj4>, @original_filename="PresidioPizza_405.jpg", 
@content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"profile[logo_image]\"; filename=\"PresidioPizza_405.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r
\n">}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mProfile Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE 
"profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[1m[36m (0.0ms)[0m  [1mBEGIN[0m
[AWS S3 200 0.505819 0 retries] 
head_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original
/selfie.jpg")  

[AWS S3 200 0.124335 0 retries] 
head_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/medium
/selfie.jpg")  

[AWS S3 200 0.118807 0 retries] 
head_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/small
/selfie.jpg")  

[AWS S3 200 0.109592 0 retries] 
head_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/thumb   
/selfie.jpg")  

Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-1nguzb2.jpg"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local  
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local 
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" -auto-orient -resize  
"250x250>" "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-14j5z1t"
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-14j5z1t"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local 
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" -auto-orient -resize 
"175x175>" "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-1rsywau"
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-1rsywau"
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" 2>NUL
Command :: identify -format %m "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]"
Command :: convert "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk20.jpg[0]" -auto-orient -resize    
"100x100>" "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-16e15ym"
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-16e15ym"
Command :: file -b --mime "C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local
/Temp/682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-1tjtjm4.jpg"


[1m[35mSQL (1.0ms)[0m  UPDATE "profiles" SET "logo_image_file_name" = $1, 
"logo_image_file_size" = $2, "logo_image_updated_at" = $3 WHERE "profiles"."id" = 1  
[["logo_image_file_name", "PresidioPizza_405.jpg"], ["logo_image_file_size", 34800], 
["logo_image_updated_at", "2014-11-10 01:59:12.534650"]]
[paperclip] deleting /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original/selfie.jpg
[AWS S3 204 0.113216 0 retries] 
delete_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original
/selfie.jpg")  

[paperclip] deleting /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/medium/selfie.jpg
[AWS S3 204 0.113074 0 retries] 
delete_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/medium
/selfie.jpg")  

[paperclip] deleting /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/small/selfie.jpg
[AWS S3 204 0.108656 0 retries] 
delete_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/small
/selfie.jpg")  

[paperclip] deleting /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/thumb/selfie.jpg
[AWS S3 204 0.106705 0 retries] 
delete_object(:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/thumb
/selfie.jpg")  

[paperclip] saving /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original/PresidioPizza_405.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.335884 0 retries] 

put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:content_length=>34800,
:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::UploadedFileAdapter:   
PresidioPizza_405.jpg,:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original/PresidioPizza_405.jpg")  

[paperclip] saving /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/medium/PresidioPizza_405.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.140086 0 retries] 
put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:content_length=>19933,
:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: 
682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-14j5z1t,
:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/medium/PresidioPizza_405.jpg")  

[paperclip] saving /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/small/PresidioPizza_405.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.142438 0 retries] 
put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:content_length=>11679,
:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: 
682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-1rsywau,
:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/small/PresidioPizza_405.jpg")  

[paperclip] saving /profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/thumb/PresidioPizza_405.jpg
[AWS S3 200 0.222046 0 retries] 
put_object(:acl=>:public_read,:bucket_name=>"phototagapp",:content_length=>5067,
:content_type=>"image/jpeg",:data=>Paperclip::FileAdapter: 
682835cfecae2078ad6fa4af85a84f1420141109-12208-192uk2020141109-12208-16e15ym,
:key=>"profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/thumb/PresidioPizza_405.jpg")  

[1m[36m (2.0ms)[0m  [1mCOMMIT[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profiles/1
Completed 302 Found in 3560ms (ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)


Started GET "/profiles/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-09 17:59:14 -0800
Processing by ProfilesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
[1m[35mProfile Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE  
"profiles"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
[1m[36mProfile Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"[0m
[1m[35mOffer Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers"  WHERE 
"offers"."offer_status" = 'On'
Rendered profiles/show.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
[1m[36mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35mProfile Load (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE 
"profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 447ms (Views: 438.6ms | ActiveRecord: 4.0ms)
```

Here is what the View displays:

```
<img alt="Presidiopizza 405" class="img-circle" src="http://phototagapp.s3.amazonaws.com 
/profiles/logo_images/000/000/001/original/PresidioPizza_405.jpg%3F1415584752" />
```

The problem seems to be the %3F1415584752 being appended to the filename. I have tested AWS S3 WITHOUT Paperclip but instead using S3_Direct_Post and images display correctly, with no weird extension and using the same AWS S3 setup/credentials. However, I'd like to use paperclip. Hoping someone can point me to the fix. I'm guessing it may be something silly.

When I access the AWS S3 Management Console, the images are being saved correctly within the correct folder structure and filename.

Here is the CORS setup.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://localhost:3000</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 has_attached_file :image,
      :logo_image, 
      :styles => { :medium => "250x250>", :small => "175x175>", :thumb => "100x100>" } 
      :storage => :s3,
       ## example credentials path
      :s3_credentials => Rails.root.join('config/amazon_s3.yml').to_s,
      :s3_protocol => 'https',
      :path => "logo/:basename.:extension"
```

Comment: thank you. unfortunately I'm still getting the %3F1415584752 at the end of my image url source. Any ideas of why it's appending the additional data?

Comment: I've started getting this problem too after having Paperclip / AWS work flawlessly for a few months. Not sure what I changed to induce this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed this problem by doing the following:

paperclip.rb initializer:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options.merge!(
  ...
  use_timestamp: false,
  ...)
```

Check here for more info:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb